# Searching using NEST does not return results, when querying on certain fields

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I'm developing an .NET application using Elastic Search. I used ES River to index the data.
Results (in Sense) look kinda like this:

```
 {
    "_index": "musicstore",
    "_type": "songs",
    "_id": "J2k-NjXjRa-mgWKAq0RMlw",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
       "songID": 42,
       "tempo": "andante",
       "metrum": "3/4 E8",
       "intonation": "F",
       "title": "Song",
       "archiveSongNumber": "3684",
       "Year": 2000,
       "Place": "London"
    }
 },
```

To access the indexed data I use NEST queries similar to this:

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.title, "Song")));
```

I'm having a problem that the query doesn't return any results, when I search for a certain field.
For instance when I search for a title, songID, tempo or archiveSongNumber the query works fine and it returns the same results as Sense, but when I search for Year, Place, metrum, etc. the query doesn't return any results, but it should (Sense does and it should).
Queries like these work (and return the right results):

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.title, "Song")));        
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.songID, 42)));
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.archiveSongNumber , "3684")));
```

Queries like these don't return any results (but they should):

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.Place, "London")));
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term(p => p.Year, 2000)));
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I mess up when I was indexing data?

**Update:** 
Mapping looks like this:

```
{
   "musicstore": {
      "mappings": {
         "songs": {
            "properties": {
               "Year": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "Place": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "archiveSongNumber": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "songID": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "intonation": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "metrum": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "tempo": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Update 2:**

ES river request looks like this:

```
PUT /_river/songs_river/_meta
{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://ip_address:1433;databaseName=database",
        "user":"user",
        "password":"password",
        "strategy":"simple",
        "poll":"300s",
        "autocommit":true,
        "fetchsize":10,
        "max_retries":3,
        "max_retries_wait":"10s",
        "index":"musicstore", 
        "type":"songs",
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer" :{ 
                "whitespace" :{ 
                    "type" : "whitespace",
                    "filter":"lowercase"
                }
            }
        },
        "sql":"some_sql_query"
    }
}
```

ES client configuration looks like this:

```
private static ElasticClient ElasticClient
{
    get
    {
        Uri localhost = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var setting = new ConnectionSettings(localhost);
        setting.SetDefaultIndex("musicstore").MapDefaultTypeNames(d => d.Add(typeof(Song), "songs"));
        setting.SetConnectionStatusHandler(c =>
        {
            if (!c.Success)
                throw new Exception(c.ToString());
        });
        return new ElasticClient(setting);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your mapping and a query that works in Sense but not NEST?

Comment: I tried a query like this in Sense: GET _search/?q=Place:London and it returns records.
Mapping looks like this:

Comment: I posted the mapping example in the first post.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at your mapping, the issue here is most likely that all of your fields are being `analyzed` when indexing, but you are using `term queries` with NEST, which are `not analyzed`, meaning they will only find exact matches.  If you don't explicitly specify an analyzer in your mappings, Elasticsearch defaults to the [standard analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#analysis-standard-analyzer).

When you perform a search in Elasticsearch using a query string, like you're doing in Sense: `GET _search/?q=Place:London`, a [query string query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) is what's being run by Elasticsearch, which is different than a [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#query-dsl-term-query).

From your examples though, it doesn't look like you are actually using [query string syntax](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax).  You probably want a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) instead:

```
client.Search<Song>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .OnField(p => p.Place)
            .Query("London")
        )
    )
);
```

If you do however want a `query string query` like the one you're performing with Sense, than you can use `QueryString`:

```
client.Search<Song>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .OnFields(p => p.Place)
            .Query("London")
        )
    )
);
```

Hope that helps.  I suggest checking out the [getting started guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/getting-started.html), specifically the section on [exact values vs. full text](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_exact_values_vs_full_text.html).

Comment: I was reading about these analyzers earlier and I agree that the usage of Term queries isn't the best.
However, I've tried both of your suggestions (match query and query string query) and none of them seem to work. Still getting 0 results. I still have to check the getting started guide. Maybe I find something useful there.

P.S.: In match query I can't use .Query("London"), but only .QueryString("London"). It's probably the same, right?

Comment: Yea, they are the same.  You're using an older version of NEST- QueryString() has been renamed to Query() in 1.0.

Comment: I've checked out the "Getting started guide" and learned a few new things. However, I still haven't figured out, why queries work in Sense, but they don't work via NEST. I've added whitespace analyzer instead of using the default one in ES river, but it made no difference, query still doesn't find any documents, which would match. Query looks like this: ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s.Query(q => q.Match(m => m.OnField(p => p.Place).QueryString("London"))));
I've added the river request and ES client configuration to the question. Do you maybe have any other suggestions, what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add "keyword" suffix to your Term Field :

```
var result = ElasticClient.Search<Song>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
            .Term(p => p
                        .Field(x => x.Year.Suffix("keyword")).Value(2000))));
```

Try it, it will work!